# Use of SERIAL and BIGSERIAL w/ EJB3 and Postgres

Tags: java, ejb, ejb-3.0, postgresql-9.1

How to use Serial and bigSerial with ejb3 and PostgreSQL?

Comment: Your question is severely lacking in detail. What problem are you having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GenerationType.IDENTITY works for Serials

`CREATE TABLE vmb_mails (ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY ,TITLE TEXT ........`

```
@Entity
@Table(name="vmb_mails")
@NamedQueries(
    @NamedQuery(name="getAllMails",query="SELECT  m from Mail m ORDER by m.entDate DESC ")
)
//@SequenceGenerator(name="Mails_Seq_Gen",sequenceName="vmb_mails_seq",allocationSize=1)
public class Mail implements Serializable
{
    private long id;
    private String title;
    private String fromAddr;

    public Mail()
    {

    }
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="ID")
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

...........
```

Comment: Which JPA implementation are you using that it works with? I had BIG problems with Hibernate and had to use explicitly defined sequences instead.

Comment: I am using EJB3.1 , while creating the table the sequence is created automatically and associated with table. so no need to create the sequence explicitly. I am using glassfish 3.1. Thanks

Comment: Glassfish 3.1 means JPA2 and EclipseLink. The issue with sequences occurs with Hibernate and a database defined directly from SQL. You should be fine. By the way, try to differentiate between Java EE 6 (the overall spec), EJB 3, and JPA; the EJB and JPA specs have separated, and talking about "EJB" when you mean "JPA" is very confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that when you say EJB3 you are intending to use the [Java Persistence API (JPA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API) which is part of the EJB3 spec in Java EE 5, and is separated out into JPA 2 in Java EE 6:

Map it using an `Integer` or `Long`, the usual `@Column` annotation, and a [`@GeneratedValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/GeneratedValue.html) annotation with a [`@SequenceGenerator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/SequenceGenerator.html).

Presuming your `serial` or `bigserial` column is an identity column and you're using JPA 2 from Java EE 6, you'd write something like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "thetable")
public class TheTable implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="tablename_id_seq", sequenceName="tablename_id_seq", allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="tablename_id_seq")
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "id", updatable=false)
    private Integer id;

    // other columns...

    // then accessors ("getters and setters")

}
```

If it's BigSerial, use `Long` instead of `Integer`, otherwise no change is required.

I have not checked to see if the above is valid in Java EE 5 with original JPA as included in EJB3. If you need to support JPA1 on Java EE 5 you may need to do some more checking. I'd recommend starting with the [JSR 220 spec for JPA](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr220/index.html) if you must support Java EE 5, but you're *way* better off just moving to JPA2 and a Java EE 6 container.

Note that it *should* be possible to simply use `GenerationType.IDENTITY` and avoid defining the sequence manually for each entity. Unfortunately, at least with Hibernate it assumes you want to use a global "hibernate" sequence for *all* tables, which is just stupid.

The `allocationSize=1` is important. JPA, frustratingly, specifies a minimum fetch size of 50, and expects sequences to increment in jumps of 50 when `nextval()` is called. Unless your sequences are defined that way, you'll get duplicate key errors.

You will need a `META-INF/persistence.xml` file to enable JPA. Access to entities is via the [`EntityManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html) which you obtain from an [`EntityMangerFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory.html) or, more commonly, by injecting it using [`@PersistenceContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/PersistenceContext.html). See the JPA documentation and endless tutorials around the 'net.

A JPA implementation comes with most application servers. Glassfish 3 ships EclipesLink and JBoss AS 7 ships Hibernate 4. See the documentation for your app server and the JPA spec.

Comment: FWIW, the JPA spec is organisationally part of the EJB spec. The [downloads for JSR-220, the EJB3 spec](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/ejb-3_0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/) include parts for 'simplified' (EJB3), 'ejbcore' (legacy EJB, i think), and 'persistence' (JPA). I agree that it's a mistake to think of JPA as part of EJB, though.

Comment: Good point @TomAnderson - the original JPA spec was part of EJB3 and in fact was part of Java EE 5, not EE 6 as I thought. The specs diverged, however, and in Java EE 6 EJB3.1 (JSR 318) was separate from JPA 2 (JSR 318). I've been working with EE6 and forgot the roots of JPA in EJB3. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @TomAnderson Fixed/clarified. It makes me wonder if the OP actually wants EJB3 _exactly_ ie JPA1 from Java EE 5, no JPA2. If so, they should've said so.

Comment: Good point that they've now very sensibly separated. I should have remembered that. And your guess is as good as mine as to what the OP actually wants!